# Accessing files stored on pc using an android app

Tags: java, android, window

I want to make an android app that will remotely connect to my computer and fetch all music files on a particular folder and then play them. The probleme is that i don't know how to fetch the files.
Do i have to set up a server ?
I connected the computer to the phone's hotspot and was able to access the xamp dashboard on the phone using the computer's ip adresse. Also the folder is a shared one.

Comment: Yes, you'd need some kind of server on your computer in order to serve the files - In most cases your phone cannot arbitrarily grab files off a computer connected to its hotspot

Comment: Samba protocol. Jcifs. Smbj.